# Image in png/base64 in svg not displaying in Safari

Tags: javascript, image, svg, safari, blockly

I embedded an image in svg and tried to plot it in Safari. While it works fine in Firefox, the image doesn't display in Safari. The code is simple and displayed below.
Now the weird thing is that when I put this code in an online test site (http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.htm), it works fine in Safari... But wherever i put the code in my web page, it doesn't work... ???
Probably a bad interaction with rest of the page, couldn't figure out where.

If someone has a suggestion, it is highly welcome.

By the way, I am trying to use Blockly for a project and this image is generated and included in the Blockly SVG. I almost succeeded to include an editor in a Blockly bloc.

Damir

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="250px" height="50px">
   <image width="200px" height="40px" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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">
   </image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in Chrome either.

The problem is that your base64 encoding is awry. Delete the two equals signs at the end of the data URI:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="250px"
     height="50px">
   <image width="200px" height="40px" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG
     goAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAyCAYAAAAZUZThAAAFx0lEQVR4nO3azWsTWx/AcdfnD8h2VlllIWTRh
     RAohBK6KyG4iuiqGHAR7NIXCAhiQKygIb5QlQqtlsZaXKQgiqFV0GkrqDE1NhVNqUlro3ltnUy+d
     3HJXNPeZ7hgoX3s7wNn08x0TsN8Z84kPZDJZEin0zJkyNgyMpkMB3RdRwixna7rEogQ/4sEIoQNC
     UQIGxKIEDYkECFsSCBC2JBAhLAhgQhhQwIRwoYEIoQNCUQIGxKIEDYkECFsSCBC2JBAhLCxrwMZG
     RkhmUzu9jTEHravA/H7/Vy6dGm3pyH2sH0dCECz2dztKYg9bMcCWV1dpb+/H6UUhw4dIpVKAZBKp
     QgEAiwuLgKQz+cJBoM8fvyYVCrFmTNniEajKKXQNI32XFZWVjh+/DgPHjxA0zRmZ2fZ2NhgcHAQp
     RQOh4Ph4WFM07S2DwaDKKVQSjE5OWnNbWxszPp5MBikWCwCcOvWLWu7crnMwMCAtd21a9eseK5fv
     86VK1c4d+4cSimcTicLCwu//Z6JvW9HAimXy7jdbvr7+0mn0wwPD6OUYnp6mo2NDbxeLz09PVQqF
     Xp7e/F6vRiGQSKRQClFOBzm8+fPnD17FqUUi4uLZLNZ62S9ceMGxWKR/v5+nE4nuq7z9OlTlFIMD
     g7SarXo7e0lHA7z5csXHj16hFIKXdfRdR2lFDMzMywuLuL3++nq6sI0TY4ePUosFsMwDLxeL93d3
     Xz48IHp6WmUUkSjUQDC4TBKKS5cuMD8/Dx9fX34fD4rTvHn2pFAEokEmqaxtrZGs9mk1WoRCoUIh
     UK0Wi3y+Tyapll3iXw+b+138OBBfv78CYBpmvh8PuLxuBXI/Pw8AB8/fkQpxdzcnHXckZERXC4X6
     +vreDwewuEwKysrAGSzWUqlElNTUzgcDlKpFI1Gg0qlYl39Q6GQdSyHw2HdWQCSySSaplEulwmFQ
     pw8eZJWqwXA69ev0TSNUqn0W++b2Pt2LJD21f7XceTIEesqe/78eZRS3L5929pvfHx825X4xIkTx
     GIxstlsx0n46x3l1+F0OimVSrx69Qq32239/PTp06yurmIYhnXs9vJvamoK+CeQRCKBy+WiXq9b8
     /j06ZN1/FAoxNDQkPXa1rmJP9eOBDI6OorL5aJarbK5uYlhGMzNzfH+/XuAbXeQr1+/An8H0tPTY
     wXSarXw+XwMDw9vOwkXFhZQSpHL5Wg2mxiGwdLSEjMzMxiGQTqdxjRNSqUSL168wO12E4vFyOfz1
     l0ll8tx9erVjhM/Ho+j6zqaplGpVKy/aesdJB6PW69JIPvHjgSSyWRQSjExMYFhGLx58walFHfv3
     sUwDHw+H4FAgO/fv+PxeAgEAh3PIA8fPqTRaDAxMWFFsPUkbD/nRCIRarUaxWIRj8fDsWPHqNfra
     JrG0NAQrVaLarVqLdVGR0dxOp0sLy8D8OzZs22BlEolNE3j8uXL1Ot18vk8XV1dRCIRANtA1tbWO
     HXqFEtLS8Dfy69IJEK1WsUwDC5evMiTJ09+6/0Vu2fHPsVKJpMdS59oNIppmty5cweHw0EulwPg3
     bt3KKW4f//+vy7N2kuwX5c4bdlsFpfLZW3r9/utq/7k5GTH7+nu7ubbt2+Uy2X6+vo6XhsbGwNgY
     GDAOvFfvny5bXlYrVa3bdeeR/uO0176zc7OAv88j5VKJRqNBm63u2Nf8f9lR78HqdVqrK+vdyxV7
     IyPj3P48GFM06RYLP6n/ZrNJuvr6/z48WPba5VKhUKh0PGw3VYsFikUCrbH2NzcZHl5mUKh8J/mL
     /58u/pF4b179+jq6pIv68SetauBPH/+nJs3b1ofnwqx1+z7fzURwo4EIoQNCUQIGxKIEDYkECFsS
     CBC2JBAhLAhgQhhQwIRwoYEIoQNCUQIGxKIEDYkECFsSCBC2JBAhLAhgQhhQwIRwoYEIoQNK5Bar
     SZDhowtQ9d1DqTT6crbt29rMmTI6BzpdLryF7moXnnVwmHFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
   </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I added the two = signs to be sure that the base64 number of characters would be divisible by 4 (heard that it was a problem in Safari). In fact, it doesn't work either if I remove them, at least on my configuration.

Comment: @user3047221 The = signs should not be there, and 2050 is not divisible by 4.

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I didn't use the NameSpaced versions of the setAttribute and other JS functions. Solved, thanks for looking.